# Python main function loop with a menu function is not working?

Tags: python, function, loops, menu, program-entry-point

I am currently a college student taking a python class. Our assignment is to create this program with functions. The main function calls the menu and then we write a loop in the main function to access the other functions based on the user response in the menu function.

I can't seem to get my loop to work. When I select a menu option nothing happens. For now, I just have print statements to test the calling of the functions. I want to make sure this works before I write the functions.

If anyone has an example of what the loop should look like to call the functions it would help me a lot.

```
def GetChoice():
    #Function to present the user menu and get their choice

    #local variables
    UserChoice = str()

    #Display menu and get choice
    print()
    print("Select one of the options listed below:  ")
    print("\tP\t==\tPrint Data")
    print("\tA\t==\tGet Averages")
    print("\tAZ\t==\tAverage Per Zone")
    print("\tAL\t==\tAbove Levels by Zone")
    print("\tBL\t==\tBelow Levels")
    print("\tQ\t==\tQuit")
    print()
    UserChoice = input("Enter choice:  ")
    print()
    UserChoice = UserChoice.upper()

    return UserChoice

def PrintData():
    print("test, test, test")

def AverageLevels():
    print("test, test, test")

def AveragePerZone():
    print("test, test, test")

def AboveLevels():
    print("test, test, test")

def BelowLevels():
    print("test, test, test")

def main():
    Choice = str()

    #call GetChoice function

    GetChoice()

    #Loop until user quits

    if Choice == 'P':
        PrintData()
    elif Choice == 'A':
        AverageLevels()
    elif Choice == 'AZ':
        AveragePerZone()
    elif Choice == 'AL':
        AboveLevels()
    elif Choice == 'BL':
        BelowLevels()


main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop should start with the following:

```
while True:
    Choice = GetChoice()
```

And the if conditions for the menu should follow at the same indent.

If you want to add an option to quit the program, add another elif statement as below:

```
elif Choice == "Q":
    break
```

This will exit the loop and thus end the program.

(Excuse the many edits - using mobile)

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign your `Choice` variable like so,

```
Choice =  GetChoice()
```

Also, note that you can also delete line like this one,

```
UserChoice = str()
```

In python, you do not need to explicitly specify variables type.

And finally another small suggestion is to compare `Choice.upper()` to the values in the bottom of your code. This way, if someone enters 'p' it will still call `PrintData()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the return value of your GetChoice() function to the name Choice:

```
Choice = GetChoice()
```